# American English for using "What do you think...?"

Tags: phrase-usage

Which is more popular, or correct?

> *What do you think are the chances of us winning?*

vs

> *What are the chances of us winning do you think?*

Comment: Not a native speaker but both sound incorrect to my ears.

Comment: Typically, neither of these are used. Instead, the question is: _What are the chances of us winning?_ To which the other person will say _I think blah blah blah._ In AmE, the _I think_ part is usually moved to the answer.

Comment: I'd say, _What do you think the chances of us winning are?_