# What are the rules for ending a sentence with a verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs, wh-questions

When do you end the sentence using the verb ‘to be’ ? Can someone tell me the difference between these three sentences.

What do you think ARE some barriers to getting legal support?

What do you think some of the barriers ARE to getting legal support?

What do you think some of the barriers to getting legal support
ARE?

———————————-

*Edit note:*

The question this has been closed as a duplicate of does not have any answer regarding ARE coming last. And the the duplicate question itself does not even ask about ARE in the middle position.

Comment: Related: ['What do you think are the chances of us winning' vs ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275385/american-english-for-using-what-do-you-think)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["What do you think" + Indirect question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/548354/what-do-you-think-indirect-question) (Ana Perez quotes the Editorial department of Cambridge University Press.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The linked-to question has no answers that answer the question! And the question itself doesn’t include the case with the extraposition from noun phrase of the non-finite relative clause!

Comment: What do you think are the advantages and disadvantages of city life? vs What do you think the advantages and disadvantages of city life are? addresses two of the options here. Yes, the option here 'What do you think some of the barriers ARE to getting legal support?' adds a layer of complexity, mixing two rules; it's a valid alternative here. But extraposition from NP has also been covered.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes .... but JL’s answer doesn’t cover ARE occurring in final position, and the self-answered one doesn’t give a cogent explanation ...

Comment: @Araucaria 'Sometimes in indirect questions[sic?] where the subject is a very long phrase, we can reverse the order of the subject (the advantages and disadvantages of city life) and the verb (are)' means that both 'What do you think the advantages and disadvantages of city life are?' and 'What do you think are the advantages and disadvantages of city life?' are considered acceptable. Add a better answer there, if you like.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That self-reported answer is gibberish. "Who do you think the thief is?" and "Who do you think is the thief?" You could hardly get a shorter subject than a two syllable one! This is not a case of heavy NP shift!

Comment: @Araucaria Add a better answer there, if you like.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I like your question, and I'll try to help out in what way I can.

You are using what is know as Indirect Questions.  So having the verb "to be", is probably better at the end.

If you remove the "do you think" part.

What are some of the barriers to getting legal support? This is the only one that works

Comment: Hello, Kenny. ELU prizes answers that are backed by linked references from recognised authorities (answers lacking these usually come across as, and too often are, merely opinion).